# Американо и чёрный кофе

Tags: значение-слов

Где-то с полгода назад активно обсуждалась идея о "непатриотичности" такого названия кофе как **"американо"**. Предлагали даже переименовать его в "рус(с)иано".

Не хочу вдаваться в политическую составляющую этого вопроса, но в связи с этими событиями мне вспомнилось наименование **"чёрный кофе"**, и я так и не смог понять: они как-то отличаются с *американо* или это разные названия для одного и того же напитка?

Comment: А также чем отличается эспрессо от американо...

Comment: Эспрессо это такая маленькая чашечка, кофе ароматный, концентрированный, его можно пить смакуя. Американо же - напиток разведённый горячей водой до размера большой (американской?) чашки. Подмена качества количеством. К эсспрессо вам подадут маленькую деликатесную печеньку или шоколадку. Спутник американо - большое калорийное сахарно- мучное образование политое глазурью. Надеюсь, теперь разница понятна ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чёрный кофе обычно означает кофе без добавления молока или сливок. Есть множество рецептов такого кофе, "американо" только один из вариантов.